# Docker Remote CA Verification

Tags: ssl, docker, centos, tls1.2

I have updated Docker 1.10 to 1.10.1 on latest CentOS 7 minimal. I am using Docker Remote Socket with self-signed certificates.

Now I get suddenly: `509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate`

I guess this is either a CentOS issue or Docker issue. Does anybody know how I can tell Docker or CentOS to verify my personal self-created authority? (file `ca.pem`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this: Environment Variable DOCKER_CERT_PATH on client machine pointed to a deprecated directory.